# VBA - Assigning Macro to Form Control Button

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

I wrote the below code in VBA to delete full rows if, in column U of Sheet21 (actually named "ROG Registration") if "Self Cancelled" or "Waitlisted" appear. When I'm on the ROG Registration tab with the VBA window open and run this it works perfectly.

I have a separate tab with macro buttons and I assigned this macro to the form control button, but when I click on the button nothing happens.

Any idea why? Could it be that I need to use the "ROG Registration" name within the code? ".Select" the tab first since it's on a different tab than the button?

```
Sub ROG_DeleteRows()

Dim r As Integer
For r = Sheet21.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "U") = "Self Cancelled" Then
         Sheet21.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(r, "U") = "Waitlisted" Then
         Sheet21.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify the sheet every time: `If Sheet21.Cells(r, "U") =...` Otherwise the active sheet (i.e., the ones with the buttons) is used by default

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it worked perfectly. Thank you!!! I thought that might be the issue, but wasn't certain where to edit (I'm fairly new to VBA).

Comment: @Lenny,, you should write this **If Sheet21.Cells(r, "U") = "Self Cancelled" Then** instead of  **If Cells(r, "U") = "Self Cancelled" Then** .